# Converting python to mysql , how can i sum next 10 rows of 1 column and enter it as another column for each row(MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql

i am new to MySql, and have slight experience in python.
I have a table with columns ***customers, date, order***.

customer : customer's name

date: running date for everyday of a year

order: 0 or 1 (1 if customer ordered on that day, 0 if customer did not order on that day)
I need to select *customers* who do not make any orders for 10 days or more.

So at first, i thought of creating a subquery with a new column(j) returning 1 if the next 10 days of ***order*** is all 0. I am having some problems doing this, i thought of using window function and partition by, however i am unable to figure out a proper condition to partition by.

Since i have a bit of experience in python, i tried to imagine how it would be done in python
which is this:

```
for i in customer:
        count=0
        for k in order:
            if k != 0:
                count=0
            else:
                count +=1
            if count == 14
                print(i)
```

Comment: SQL is a set oriented, declarative language. You don't perform calculation steps, you describe what you want and the server creates the necessary steps and executes them in the most efficient way. In this case, you probably need `SELECT customerID,COUNT(distinct date) FROM Orders GROUP BY customer HAVING count(distinct date)<10`. You tell the server to group orders by customer, count the distinct dates by customer and return those that have <10 distinct dates

Comment: this query seems to be looking for customers with less than 10 orders in total. i am looking for customers with 0 orders for 10 consecutive days. That being said, for each customer, there are rows for each date of the year, with some entries for order column being 0 or 1. I think i did not explain my problem well enough. i made an edit to the main question with further explanations

Comment: That's [a gaps-and-islands problem](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-gaps-and-islands-analysis/) - you're looking for a gap of 10 days in a customer's orders. You can use `LEAD` and `ROW_NUMBER` in MySQL 8 to find gaps, just like other databases.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos ahh, yes. That seems to be what i am looking for. Thanks for the help! I have never come across this problem before.

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Comment: In MySQL 8+ you may simply calculate window SUM() in 10-rows window.

Comment: @Akina How can i specify the 10 rows? i somehow managed to use the gaps and island to solve it. But the code is abit complicated. Looking to simplify the code as much as possible.

Comment: *How can i specify the 10 rows?* o_O `.. OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY .. ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 9 FOLLOWING)`. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Window Function Frame Specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html).